# How to get child items specific format

Tags: sitecore-mvc, c#

I need show the product and Version from the below folder structure. Please help to achieve on this.

Requirement Screen Shot
[image: Need to show product and Version]

Sitecore Folder Structure

[image: sitecore folder structure]

So far I wrote some code for review

```
var item = ItemHelper.GetChildItems("{D25F6421-4578-4EB2-8C6D-C9BE2C355099}");

public static IEnumerable<Item> GetChildItems(string itemId)
{
    var sitecoreItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(itemId));
  
    if (sitecoreItem.HasChildren)
    {
        return sitecoreItem.GetChildren().InnerChildren;

    }

    return null;
}

 var productList = item.Where(x => x.Fields["ProductTitle"] != null).Select(y =>
 new Product
 {
     Name = y.Name,
     Id = y.ID,
     ProductTitle = y.Fields["ProductTitle"].Value,
     Version = y.GetChildren().InnerChildren
 });
```

I need version list also to bind.

Comment: Please share what you have done so far and maybe people can help identify a problem

Comment: @DeanOBrien code added. Please review on it. if you aware of it.

Comment: You need to add more information to this like which is that item that has id - {D25F6421-4578-4EB2-8C6D-C9BE2C355099} ? Definition of Product object. Out of my assumption, try this - Version = y.GetChildren()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public static IEnumerable<Models.Product> GetProductList(ID itemId)
 {
     var childItem = GetChildItems(itemId.ToString());

     IEnumerable<Models.Product> productList = new List<Models.Product>();

     if (childItem != null)
     {
         productList = childItem.Where(x => x.Fields["ProductTitle"] != null)
                             .Select(y => new Models.Product
                             {
                                 Name = y.Name,
                                 Id = y.ID,
                                 ProductTitle = y.Fields["ProductTitle"].Value,
                                 ProductItem = y,
                                 Version = y.GetChildren().InnerChildren
                                 .Select(z => new ProductVersion
                                 {
                                     Name = z.Name,
                                     Id = z.ID,
                                     VersionItem = z,
                                     ModuleList = z.GetChildren().InnerChildren
                                      .Select(m => new ProductModule
                                      {
                                          Name = m.Name,
                                          Id = m.ID,
                                          TemplateId = m.TemplateID,
                                          ModuleItem = m
                                      })

                                 })
                             });

     }


     return productList;
 }
```

Comment: Above code Will it be faster?  if i have more than 500 records.  @Vikrant Punwatkar

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
var versions = Sitecore.Data.Managers.ItemManager.GetVersions(item);
var allVersions = versions.Select(x => item.Database.Items[item.ID, item.Language, x]);
```

Comment: version is custom folder, not sitecore version. please read the question and see the screenshot.